# type anycompatiblearray does not exist PostgreSQL 12.15

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to run this query

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_concatenation_aggregate(anycompatiblearray) (SFUNC=array_cat, STYPE=anycompatiblearray)
DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS array_concatenation_aggregate(anycompatiblearray)
```

but I am having this error on this

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42704 (undefined_object) type anycompatiblearray does not exist
```

According to release notes I know this `anycompatiblearray` is only with latest versions but is it possible to make it work somehow, and add `anycompatiblearray` type to old version?

any help or guidance would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Only if you program it into the source code and recompile it, but upgrading is much easier

Comment: I have 4 applications that use version 12. and only this one uses the latest. Is it possible to have both versions? without breaking any thing.

Comment: but isn't there any alternative to run this query? I am not an expert in PSQL but before this `anycompatiblearray` how everyone was creating such `AGGREGATE` ?

Comment: different version afaik no

Comment: It is possible to run different versions of Postgres  on the same machine. 1) They will be entirely different instances. 2) They will need to listen on different ports.  3) How this can be done depends on your OS and the method you used to install Postgres.